# cannot use Directory.GetFiles to get the server path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the view mode, I use the following code, it works

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
    string imgPath = "/Temp/2490/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";

    <img width="200" height="200" src="@Url.Content(imgPath)" />
}
```

I want to let the user view the documents and then download it, I use the following code and the Folder routes to C:/Temp/2490, and sometimes chrome don't let me view the local files, what is wrong with the following codes?

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@Url.Content("/Temp/2490"), "*.jpg, *.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Content(file)">Document</a>
    </li>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles` takes path as a parameter. This is not a url. Here you would want to pass `@"C:\Temp\2490`.